# Github Action for Synching a fork

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I'm writing an action to update a fork from upstream. Manually, this is quite simple. I'm able to do it locally by, in the forked repo, running

```sh
git remote add upstream https://github.com/my-user/myapp.git
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/main
git push origin main
```

I tried creating a github workflow (Which of course lies as a commit on the forked version)

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  fetch-upstream:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Fetch Upstream
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: myorg/myapp
          token: ${{ github.token }}
      - name: Configure git
        run: |
          git config --global user.name "CI Bot"
          git config --global user.email "noreply@myemail.com"
          git remote add upstream https://github.com/my-user/myapp.git
        shell: bash
      - name: Fetch and merge
        id: fetch-merge
        run: |
          git fetch upstream
          git checkout main
          lines=$( git diff main..upstream/main -- . ':(exclude).github/**' | wc -l )
          echo "Number of detected line changes: $lines"
          if [ $lines -gt 0 ]; then
            git merge upstream/main
            git push
          fi
        shell: bash
```

However, when I do this I get `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`.

I've also tried running it with `--allow-unrelated-histories` with `-Xtheirs` which works, but doesn't seem to delete files, if they are deleted at the upstream `my-user/myapp` repo.

I've seen some marketplace actions like [fork-sync](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/fork-sync) however, I don't get why it's a node action, when this **should** be pretty simple.

Comment: The `checkout@v2` action makes a *shallow* clone by default, which lacks history. The subsequent `git fetch` won't get you enough to work. Turn off shallow cloning (by setting the depth to 0 or using the v1 checkout action). (Note that this is a GitHub-specific thingy, although shallow clones in general are generic Git.)

Comment: I see! Thank you so much!